# Swagger-net (or swashbuckle) : how to set the namespace in the xml requests?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.examples

is there a way to generate example requests with xml namespaces using Swagger-net? Or in swashbuckle?

I was thinking of something like:

```
 [SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK,
 typeof(ResponseExample), xmlnamespace="wanted xml namespace goes here...")]
```

Comment: Interesting!  I never used the xmlnamespace before... why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swagger-Net you have `SwaggerResponse` you can call it like these:

```
[SwaggerResponse(400, "Bad request")]
public class SwaggerAnnotatedController : ApiController
{
    [SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Type = typeof(int), MediaType = "text", Examples = 123)]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid message", typeof(HttpError))]
    public int Create(Message message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [SwaggerResponse( 200, Type = typeof( IEnumerable<Message> ), TypeName = "Messages" )]
    public IEnumerable<Message> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

But I never had a need for xmlnamespace so there is no such an option:

https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/blob/master/Swagger.Net/Swagger/Annotations/SwaggerResponseAttribute.cs

but if you can provide precise details of how is that xmlnamespace used I can add it.